# Unable to resolve The file '/_controltemplates/xxxxxxx.ascx' does not exist. 

Tags: user-controls, code-access-security

I have developed a custom user control and loading it in a webpart, the aim to run the webpart from bin with custom policy.

I made the WSP Builder generate the CAS policy and it does contain the entry the sharepoint permission.

the issue gets resolved it the binaries are moved to GAC or setting the wep app to FullTrust.

Note : I am using Sharepoint guidance :)

Please help me to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a control template you also need permissions in your CAS for ASP.NET hosting and access to the file system. Just SP permissions is not enough.